# is probability (serving 2 friends and three people appeared)= probability (three people appeared)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-probability

There are 3 friends of Michael: Tommy, Arthur, John. Each friend decides
whether or not they want to come to lunch in his home restaurant following the socialdistancing norm, independently of the others. Tommy wants to come with a probability
0.8. Arthur wants to come with a probability 0.6. John wants to come with a probability
0.1. Unfortunately, if all 3 of them want to come, he must turn one of them away. Since
the table capacity is 2 guests. Otherwise, he will take everyone that comes. Let X be the
number of friends that Michael serves at lunch. What is the expectation E[X]?
(a) 1.15
(b) 1.38
(c)1.45
(d)0.95

given solution :The sample space is$S_X = {0, 1, 2}$.
since we can have anywhere from 0 to
2 people. By independence,
$P(X = 0) = P(T
^C, A^C, J^C) = P(T
^C)P(A
^C)P(J
^C) = (0.2)(0.4)(0.9) = 0.072\\
P(X = 1) = P(T, A^C, J^C) + P(T
^C, A, J^C) + P(T
^C, A^C, J) = 0.404\\
P(X = 2) = 1 − P(X = 0) − P(X = 1) = 0.524\\
E[X] = \sum 
i.PX(i) = 1.452 $

my solution :$0(0.072) +1(0.404)+ 2(0.476) + 2(\frac{3}{8}) 0.048=1.392$

where $0.476$ is probability (exactly 2 people appeared)

$\frac{3}{8}$ = probability(2 people served /3 people appeared)

please tell where I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is multiplying the last term by $\frac{3}{8}$. Rest is correct. Please note that $0.048$ is the probability of all three of them appearing for lunch and it is *certain* that if all three appear, only *two* will be served. That is why the book solution considers cases $ \small X = 0, X = 1$ and $ \small X \geq 2$.

$ \small P(X \geq 2) = 1 - P(X = 0) - P(X = 1) = 0.524$, which is same as $ \small P(X = 2) + P(X = 3) = 0.476 + 0.048$